# Многоуровневое меню

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Есть код с использованием jQuery для открытия многоуровнего меню по клику. Но при раскрытии внутри одного и того же уровня других уровней, они накладываются и теряются. Ищу решение как сделать так, что бы при открытии уровня, другой такой же закрывался. Если проще на примере кода, при открытии Ссылки 3, уровень из Ссылки 1 закрывался

```js
$(function() {
  $('.--clickable>a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $(this).next('ul').toggleClass('--active');
  });
});
```

```css
li>ul {
  display: none;
}

li>ul.--active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="menu-first">
  <li class="menu-first__link"><a href="">Пункт 1</a></li>
  <li class="menu-first__link --clickable"><a href="">Пункт 2</a>
    <ul class="menu-second">
      <li class="menu-second__link --clickable"><a href="">Ссылка 1</a>
      
        <ul class="menu-third">
          <li class="menu-third__link"><a href="">Товар 1</a></li>
          <li class="menu-third__link"><a href="">Товар 2</a></li>
          <li class="menu-third__link"><a href="">Товар 3</a></li>
          <li class="menu-third__link"><a href="">Товар 4</a></li>
        </ul>
        
      </li>
      <li class="menu-second__link"><a href="">Ссылка 2</a></li>
      <li class="menu-second__link --clickable"><a href="">Ссылка 3</a>

        <ul class="menu-third">
          <li class="menu-third__link"><a href="">Товар 1</a></li>
          <li class="menu-third__link"><a href="">Товар 2</a></li>
          <li class="menu-third__link"><a href="">Товар 3</a></li>
          <li class="menu-third__link"><a href="">Товар 4</a></li>
        </ul>

      </li>
      <li class="menu-second__link"><a href="">Ссылка 4</a></li>
    </ul>

  </li>
  <li class="menu-first__link"><a href="">Пункт 3</a></li>
  <li class="menu-first__link"><a href="">Пункт 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста замените ссылки на тругой тег, иначе просиходит переходит и меню пропадает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  $('.--clickable>span').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).next('ul').hasClass('--active')) { //Если подменю уже открыто,
      $(this).next('ul').toggleClass('--active'); //закрываем его
      return false; //Прерываем дальнейшее выполнение функции
    }
    let menu_second = $(this).closest('.menu-second').find('ul.--active'); //Ищем все открытые подменю текущего уровня через общего родителя по классу .--active
    $(menu_second).each(function(e) { //Пробегаемся по получившемуся набору объектов циклом
      $(this).toggleClass('--active'); //Удаляем у каждого объекта класс .--active, тем самым закрывая ВСЕ подменю текущего уровня
    });
    $(this).next('ul').toggleClass('--active'); //И открываем подменю, которое нам необходимо
  });
});
```

```css
li>ul {
  display: none;
}

li>ul.--active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="menu-first">
  <li class="menu-first__link"><span href="">Пункт 1</span></li>
  <li class="menu-first__link --clickable"><span href="">Пункт 2</span>
    <ul class="menu-second">
      <li class="menu-second__link --clickable"><span href="">Ссылка 1</span>

        <ul class="menu-third">
          <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 1</span></li>
          <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 2</span></li>
          <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 3</span></li>
          <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 4</span></li>
        </ul>

      </li>
      <li class="menu-second__link"><span href="">Ссылка 2</span></li>
      <li class="menu-second__link --clickable"><span href="">Ссылка 3</span>

        <ul class="menu-third">
          <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 1</span></li>
          <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 2</span></li>
          <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 3</span></li>
          <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 4</span></li>
        </ul>

      </li>
      <li class="menu-second__link"><span href="">Ссылка 4</span></li>
    </ul>

  </li>
  <li class="menu-first__link"><span href="">Пункт 3</span></li>
  <li class="menu-first__link"><span href="">Пункт 4</span></li>
</ul>
```

P.S. Заменил ссылку на тег `span`, чтобы меню не пропадало из-за перехода

Comment: Большое вам спасибо, то, что мне и нужно было. Я немного подправил код под себя и добавил кнопку для раскрытия первого уровня, но тут столкнулся с проблемой, что при открытии/закрытии кнопкой, открытые вторые уровни так и оставались, подскажите решение, что бы они тоже скрывались при раскрытии кнопкой, как и третьи уровни

Comment: @MichaelKardamon, по сути вы можете просто повторить код из ответа для всех своих уровней. Либо написать функцию, которая бы принимала в качестве аргументов текущий элемент и поиском родителя определяла, какие уровни стоит закрыть